# React DnD / Redux - Re-render component while dragging

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-dnd

Roughly summarized, I am using the following structure (using Redux):

```
<Provider store=..>
  <MyApp>
    <Connect(DragDropContext)>
      <DragDropContext>
        <div id=main>
          <DragLayer></DragLayer>
          <MyComponent props={draggingElement:store.draggingElement}>
            <div class=container> 
              <DropTarget props={draggingElement:this.props.draggingElement}>
                <div id=indicator>
                  Currently dragging #2 which can be dropped here
                </div>
              </DropTarget>
              <div id=elements>
                <DragSource key=1></DragSource>
                <DragSource key=2></DragSource>
                <DragSource key=3></DragSource>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class=container> 
              <DropTarget props={draggingElement:this.props.draggingElement}>
                <div id=indicator>
                  Currently dragging #2 which can not be dropped here.
                </div>
              </DropTarget>
              <div id=elements>
                <DragSource key=1></DragSource>
                <DragSource key=2></DragSource>
                <DragSource key=3></DragSource>
              </div>
            </div>
          </MyComponent>
        </div>
      </DragDropContext>
    </Connect(DragDropContext)>
  </App>
</Provider>
```

Now in an all DragSources, I am listening to the `beginDrag` event and firing an action which updates the store with some information about the item being dragged at the moment (`draggingElement`).
`MyComponent` gets this information passed as a property but doesn't use it in any way other than passing it down to all DropTargets, still as a property.
Now in all DropTargets, I render a message depending on whether the element being dragged can be dropped there or not.

So far so good, unfortunately, as soon as I start dragging an element I get the following error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined
    at Object.a [as getDragPreviewOffset] (core-2fc0801472.js:31485)
    at t.handleTopDragStart (core-2fc0801472.js:31485)
```

It seems that `MyComponent` gets replaced entirely in the DOM as soon as it receives the property with the information about the dragging element.
And since the dragging element is also a child of `MyComponent`, it gets replaced as well and the drag operation fails.
If I put the following code in `MyComponent` everything works:

```
    shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.draggingElement !== this.props.draggingElement) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    },
```

But now the DropTargets are not re-rendered anymore as well (since they are children of `MyComponent`) and don't display the required information.

What can I do about this? And specifically, why is the DOM of `MyComponent` being replaced entirely if the new property only affects a small part of it?